# Are these TransformedDistributions identical?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

If A1 and A2 are independent random variables, and B1 and B2 are as well, then are the following TransformedDistributions the same?

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]1 = TransformedDistribution[(w1A1 A1 + (1 - w1A1) B1) + (w2A2 A2 + (1 - w2A2) B2), {A1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[muA1, sdA1], B1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[muB1, sdB1], A2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[muA2, sdA2], B2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[muB2, sdB2]}]
```

and

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]2 = TransformedDistribution[(w1A A + (1 - w1A) B) + (w2A A + (1 - w2A) B), {A \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[muA, sdA], B \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[muB, sdB]}]
```

In other words, when constructing a TransformedDistribution, does every distribution need to be stated explicitly, even when some random variables follow distributions that are identical?

Comment: A1 and A2 are not distributions but random variates. If they are independent, A1+A2 and A1+A1=2A1 do not follow the same distribution!

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question, and now see what you mean.

Comment: (1) You edited out a critical term (_identically distributed_). Better wording could be: _A1 and A2 are iid (independent identically distributed) random variables_. (2) The two distribution are not related. (3) You probably meant to ask if there is shorter way to write something like `{A1 \[Distributed] dist, A2 \[Distributed] dist, A3 \[Distributed] dist}` when A1, A2 and A3 are iid rvs. If that's the case, there is: you can use `{{A1, A2, A3}\[Distributed] ProductDistribution[{dist,3}]}`